# updating android app version and build number using script without changing androidManifest VersionCode and VersionName

Tags: java, android

I have been able to automatic change my versionCode to be used as build number in androidmanifest.xml to my current git commit number through a script file before game start. But due to a particular reason, i dont want to use versionCode to be used as my game build number. I want to use something other than versionCode and VersionName where i can save my git commit number through script before game start and later during game i can read that value and show in my game. So i need two things

1. how to create an extra Tag in androidManifest file where i can save this value
2. And script to change that Tag value to be used in the script file before game run

i use the following script to change versionCode tag in manifest

```
newverfull=$(git --git-dir="../../.git" --work-tree="../../" rev-list master | wc -l)

manf=AndroidManifest.xml

newvers=`echo $newverfull | sed 's/[^0-9].*$//'`

vers=`sed -n '/versionCode=/s/.*"\([0-9][0-9]*\)".*/\1/p' $manf`

sed /versionCode=/s/'"'$vers'"'/'"'$newvers'"'/ $manf  >new$manf && cp new$manf $manf && rm -f new$manf
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: For the script, what OS are you using?  What are you building with?  ANT, Maven?  Other?

Comment: i'm building with android 4.0.3 and not using any ANT, Maven. Just wrote a simple .sh script file and run it before my game launch to change the manifest andriodCode tag in manifest tag which i dont want to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to change my script posted earlier. I also made a meta data in the manifest file and changed its value using the script below.

Thanks for the help. Cheers!

```
newverfull=$(git --git-dir="../../.git" --work-tree="../../" rev-list master | wc -l)
manf=AndroidManifest.xml
verbase=`echo $newverfull | sed 's/\(.*\.\)\([0-9][0-9]*\).*$/\1/'`
vername=`sed -n '/GameVersion/s/.*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' $manf`
sed /GameVersion/s/'"'$vername'"'/'"'$verbase'"'/ $manf  >new$manf && cp new$manf $manf && rm -f new$manf
```

Comment: use "sed -i" to replace in file without this copy like this: `sed -i /GameVersion/s/'"'$vername'"'/'"'$verbase'"'/ $manf`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this shell script.

https://github.com/eaglesakura/jenkins-script/blob/master/update-AndroidManifest.sh

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example.  The custom tag is GameVersion.

```
<application android:name=".MyApplication"
             android:icon="@drawable/icon"
             android:label="@string/app_name">

    <meta-data android:name="GameVersion" android:value="1.9" />

    <activity android:name="com.someone.something.MainActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
              android:screenOrientation="sensor"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
```

To access it:

```
    ApplicationInfo ai = _context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(_context.getPackageName(),PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    ai.metaData.get("GameVersion")
```

As you can see, you need a context to get a reference to the PackageManager.  I prefer to use getApplicationContext() to do this but it's fine to use your activity context if that's where you are getting the data.

Comment: its alright with meta data but how do i access this meta data field whithin a .sh script file and change its value.

Comment: Why can't you just change the script you already have?  You might also want to think about changing to ANT or some other build tool which automates thigns like this.  http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html.  As to .sh, sorry, I don't do Linux.

Comment: Great.  I'm pleased that it helped.  Please accept my answer so that other people can find it, or, accept your own answer.